# If I sell to close an ITM call option days before expiration, am I liable for any call outs?

Tags: call-options

If I sell to close an ITM call option days before expiration, am I liable for any call outs?

Comment: What do you mean by "call outs"? If you sell to close an option you are out of the position and have no further liability whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming by "liable for any call outs" you mean will you be obligated (or even able) to buy the stock if it expires ITM, the answer is no. If you sell to close a long position (or buy to close a short position), you are no longer under any obligation whatsoever.